# UI freezes very often after moving the home directory

Tags: freeze, live-cd, gui, home-directory

I maybe wrong but from what I understand I should've done the movement of the home directory to another partition from a liveCD, what I didn't do.

I think that made the UI (sidebar, upperbar) and some other programs just freezes and I think crash as well. The occurance ranges from every couple of seconds to every every couple of hours.

Didn't find anything is the syslog. Anywhere else to look at?

One thing is sure - I didn't do anything else that could've caused it, and barely ever occured before.

Comment: try reinstalling gnome-shell / unity might help

Comment: Should I reinstall both? I am using 12.04 with unity.

Comment: My system also got stuck due to some installation i done with compiz. I come over that by reinstalling the esktop environment please try and reinstalling the environment you are using.

Comment: I've reinstalled unity. ATM everything is smooth (5 minutes passed)... But we'll see. If that works, should I post it as an answer or will one of you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't say I truly solved the problem. 
I reinstalled Unity. For a day it was fine but then it looked like it came back, but before I got the time make sure it was back, I installed Gnome Shell instead of Unity (for irrelevant reasons).
I can confirm that now (using Gnome Shell) I am not having the issues I experienced, so I **assume** reinstalling Unity in one or another way should work.